# not found external bd in folder assets Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, external, assets

I am trying to connect to an external database via a hosted file in the assets folder. I think introduce either all statements but when launching the program tells me that the 'tareas' table is missing. I leave the code ...

Code SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE 'tareas' (
'_id'   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
'nombre'    TEXT,
'observaciones' TEXT,
'fecha' INTEGER
```

);

```
INSERT INTO 'tareas' VALUES ('1','Programming',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO 'tareas' VALUES ('2','Examn database',NULL,'18/12/2014');
```

Code Java class bbdd:

```
public class BBDD extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.ros.juanmanuel.appnotas2/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "bbdd";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

public BBDD(Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist

    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.i("BBDD","Base de datos creada correctamente.");

        /*try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }*/
    }

}

private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

public void openDataBase(int flag) throws SQLException {

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, flag);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try {
        copyDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {

}

public Tareas pruebaConsulta(int id){

    Tareas t;

    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tareas WHERE _id="+id, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    t = new Tareas(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));

    return t;
}
```

}

Code Java (Class where open's db)(Method select()):

public class ListaTareas extends ActionBarActivity {

```
private TextView textoSeleccionado;
private Principal princ;
private BBDD myDbHelper = null;
private ListView lista;
private Adapter adapter;
private Tareas t;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_tareas);

    darValorLabel();

    myDbHelper = new BBDD(this);

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("BBDD", "Error al crear la base de datos (Clase.Principal)");
    }

    myDbHelper.openDataBase(SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_lista_tareas, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public String recogerParametro(){

    return getIntent().getExtras().getString("NombreSeleccion");
}

private void darValorLabel(){

    textoSeleccionado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbListaTareas);
    textoSeleccionado.setText("Lista Tareas: "+recogerParametro());
}

public void cambiarVentanaAdd(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PantallaAdd.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public TextView getTextoSeleccionado() {
    return textoSeleccionado;
}

public void setTextoSeleccionado(TextView textoSeleccionado) {
    this.textoSeleccionado = textoSeleccionado;
}

/*public void consultar(int id){
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaTareas);
    myDbHelper.pruebaConsulta(id);

    List<Tareas> listaT = new ArrayList<Tareas>();

    listaT.add(myDbHelper.pruebaConsulta(id));

    ArrayAdapter<Tareas> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tareas>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            listaT
    );

    lista.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}*/

public void select(View view){
    TextView pantalla = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pantallaPrueba);

    t = new Tareas();

    t= myDbHelper.pruebaConsulta(1);

    pantalla.setText(t.getNombreTarea());
}
```

}

Error:

```
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17477)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tareas (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tareas
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:886)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:497)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
        at com.ros.juanmanuel.appnotas2.BBDD.pruebaConsulta(BBDD.java:147)
        at com.ros.juanmanuel.appnotas2.ListaTareas.select(ListaTareas.java:128)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3602)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17477)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your app and Reinstall, you have a old version of you database ,

Yout table 'tareas' has not been created, or had another name.